# iMac Scrolling effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just saw this fiddle on codepen http://codepen.io/mariusbalaj/pen/qcfox and really like the effect. Now I wanted to reproduce this (generic) with all kinds of different image sizes.

I don't get the relation between the different width and heights. Maybe one of you can shed some light on this.

Especially the class .mac with a height of 613px a width of 764px and the margin of 1340px. How is this connected to the original image size of 2548x2052px?

```
.mac {
  height: 613px;
  width: 764px;
  margin: 1340px auto 100px;
  background: white url("http://i.imgur.com/AyELvGR.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  -webkit-background-size: 764px 613px;
  background-size: 764px 613px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.mac.intro {
  position: fixed;
  width: 2548px;
  z-index:9999;
  height: 2052px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -300px;
  margin-left: -1274px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
}
```

Thanks in advance